# why proc file doesn't work with one columns

Tags: bash, latex, pdflatex

I was trying to make all the combinations of supported documents formate with their attributes in latex using bash scripting.
for eg:-

```
All formats = [article, IEEEtran, proc, report, book, memoir, letter]
```

Their attribute =

```
11pt, 12pt | a4paper, letterpaper | twocolumn, onecolumn | twoside, oneside | landscape, portrait
```

I use the brute force approach to make all the possible combinations.

One of the combination is:

```
{11pt, a4paper, onecolumn, oneside, portrait}[proc]
```

but when this combination is formed while the execution of the bash script, it shows the following error:-

```
Document Class: proc 2014/09/29 v1.3l Standard LaTeX document class ! Class proc Error: Option `onecolumn' not supported.
```

The script:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -a size=(11pt 12pt)
declare -a paper=(a4paper letterpaper)
declare -a side=(twoside oneside)
declare -a column=(twocolumn onecolumn)
declare -a orientation=(landscape portrait)
declare -a class=(article IEEEtran proc report book memoir letter)

count=0
prop=()

for i in "${size[@]}"
do
    for j in "${paper[@]}"
    do
        for k in "${column[@]}"
        do
            for l in "${side[@]}"
            do
                for m in "${orientation[@]}"
                do
                    for cll in "${class[@]}"
                    do
                        count=$(( count + 1 ))
                        echo "
                        \documentclass[$i , $j , $k , $l, $m]{$cll}
                        \usepackage{blindtext}
                        \begin{document}

                        \Blindtext

                        \end{document}
                        " > file$count.tex
                        #pdflatex file$count.tex
                        mkdir q2_pdfdoc
                        mv file$count.tex q2_pdfdoc
                        #rm file$count.*
                    done
                done
            done
        done
    done
done
```

Comment: I don't see any bash code in your question.

Comment: The `proc` document class does  not support the `onecolumn` option, I think. So, if I am right, you get an error because what you try is not valid. Note that this is exactly what the error message says...

Comment: Some remarks: `declare -a` can be avoided; `prop=()` is unused; `mkdir` might be called once before the `for`'s + `exit` on fail; the two first `done` are badly indented.

Comment: Like @EdouardThiel mentionned, the `mkdir` should only be done once.  I indented your code, it is much easier to see the `for, do done` loops like this.